# Explanation of nullsafe 

Tags: mysql, null, comparison

I have realized that these two queries do not work if 'fk_building' is null. I don't understand why, and cant seem to find a good explanation as it is kind of hard to google. Can someone explain why the hell !=3 doesnt return everything that is not 3??? including null rows? Why do I need to use <=> ?

```
update floor set fk_building = 3 where fk_building != 3 and floor_id = 1;
```

or

```
select * from floor where fk_building != 3
```

do not work where fk_building is null.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to make it less angry and more focused. And I thought that the "not equals" operator in most Sql dialects (including MySql) was `<>`.

Comment: there is no need to repeat something from the answer as an update in your question. It is not part of the question, it is part of the answer. Thank littlebobbytables by upvoting his answer and mark the answer as accepted if it fixes your problem. Please don't keep re-adding it to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the "Common Mistakes" section on `NULL` values on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Common_mistakes).

From the entry:

> For example, a WHERE clause or conditional statement might compare a column's value with a constant. It is often incorrectly assumed that a missing value would be "less than" or "not equal to" a constant if that field contains Null, but, in fact, such expressions return Unknown

As users have suggested, you can use a null safe operator if your RDBMS allows it, or check for `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

use the null safe operator

```
 update floor set fk_building = 3 where (not fk_building <=> 3) and floor_id = 1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: doesnt work on the example query

Comment: updated answer works...but who wants to use not just to say != 3??

Answer (score 0):

Rather than get pissed off, why not just do:

```
update floor set fk_building = 3 where (fk_building != 3 OR fk_building IS NULL) and floor_id = 1;
```

Comment: Understood, but I am trying to understand why this is necessary for the future. you can also do fk_building <=> 3. But why is null ever = 3?

Comment: @TonyGutierrez - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Common_mistakes

Comment: It is necessary because != and <> are not null safe.

Comment: Littlebobbytables, thats is what I wanted. Thanks. Add an answer and ill credit you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use x <=> 3 to test for both.

EDIT: in your case it be 'not x <=> 3'

Comment: doesnt work in the example query